# How to make audio track default in ffmpeg while adding audio?

Tags: ffmpeg

I use this command to add audio to my video:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i audio.mp3 -map 0 -map 1:a -c:v copy -shortest output.mkv
```

Now I want to choose default audio from all audio. How can I achieve that in single go by tweaking above command?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`-disposition`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options).

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i audio.mp3 -map 0 -map 1:a -c copy -disposition:a 0 -disposition:a:1 default -shortest output.mkv
```

Comment: Just tried this and while it still added the new audio track in the second position (a:1 instead of a:0) it is listed as default.